# How to get a welcome message on teams even before user sends any message

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have deployed my bot on teams channel.

I would like to send a welcome message to a new user even before user sends a message to the bot.

can we achieve this for teams channel?

If yes, which event can be used to get that user is accessing bot for the first time.

Comment: What programming language are you building your bot with ?

Comment: I am using C# library for building bot

Comment: Yes then check my answer, that event will trigger once a user joins the conversation

Answer (score 1):

The [conversationUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#conversationupdate) event with the membersAdded object in the payload is sent when either a bot is added to a team or a new user is added to a team where a bot has been added. It is always a good practice to send a [welcome message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#best-practice-welcome-messages-in-teams) introducing the bot to all the users. Ensure that your bot responds to the conversationUpdate message, with the teamsAddMembers eventType in the channelData object. Also, keep in mind that the memberAdded ID is the bot's App ID itself, because the same event is sent when a user is added to a team.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Refer to the [welcome-user](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user) sample in the BotBuilder Samples.

Comment: Is there a way to get the user's locale using the `conversationUpdate` event so we can localize the welcome message? Seems like this is an open issue https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2920#issuecomment-582458342 and the proposed solution in directline is not found in teams

Comment: As of now, the bot will have to wait for the user to message as the message activity has clientInfo filled out in channelData with locale information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ConversationUpdate** event `ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate // in c#`

Answer (score 0):

When a bot is installed, your bot receives a [conversationUpdate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications). You can then send a proactive message to the user. Could you please try sending a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages) and let us know if you face any issues?

Comment: If user sends a message to a bot then only ConversationUpdate event is triggering, not on accessing Bot contact. Any other way or do you have any working example in Bot framework v4?

Comment: Your Bot will receive a ConversationUpdate event when your bot is installed in a team. Could you please put a debugger in your application and then install it and see if you are getting the conversationUpdate event.

Comment: Actually I am trying for 1:1/Personal conversations, not for teams.

Comment: @RutujLangalia You receive a conversationUpdate when app is added to a personal scope also.

Comment: I have attached relevant files to one of the similar issue on Github. Please check if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RutujLangalia Could you please try this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) for sending proactive messages?

Comment: I already tried this and for this users must have chatted once then only it will send a proactive message whereas I need to send welcome message when user accesses bot contact before even user sends a message.

Comment: @RutujLangalia User needs to install the app to get a proactive message. What do you mean by user accesses bot contact?